# get utf-8 character code given a shift-jis character code?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, shift-jis

In my program I get shift-jis character codes as Python integers which I need to convert to their corresponding utf8 character codes (which should also be in integers).
How can I do that?
For ASCII you have the helpful functions ord()/chr() which allows you to convert an integer into an ASCII string which you can easily convert to unicode later. I can't find anything like that for other encodings.

Using Python 2.

EDIT: the final code. Thanks everyone:

```
def shift_jis2unicode(charcode): # charcode is an integer
    if charcode <= 0xFF:
        string = chr(charcode)
    else:
        string = chr(charcode >> 8) + chr(charcode & 0xFF)

    return ord(string.decode('shift-jis'))

print shift_jis2unicode(8140)
```

Comment: It's unusual to get them as integers rather than as bytes - is that something you can change?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. BTW, I think "bytes" is something new in Python 3, I use 2.

Comment: Python 2 `str` works like bytes, and it has a `bytes` alias in 2.6 and 2.7.

Comment: Well, I wish I could. That's why I posted this question. If I could get it as string, I could just do mystr.decode('shift_jis') and then ord() on that. But I can't.

Comment: Show some sample data to give us a better idea of what you're working with.

Comment: `ord()` would give you unicode code points, not utf-8. That may be what you want, but those are very different things.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I explained exactly what I have and what I need to do with it.

Comment: Thomas K: I guess you're right. Still, I haven't even reached that point: I don't even know how to get the integer character code into a string of shift-jis encoding.

Comment: Please don't use `string` as a variable name.

Comment: I thought it was "str" which was reserved. Anyway, not even in a function?

Comment: "str" is a built-in type.  "string" is a built-in module.  Technically you can use them for variable names, but it's confusing.  Better to avoid them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as "utf8 character codes (which should also be in integers)".

Unicode defines "code points", which are integers.  UTF-8 defines how to convert those code points to an array of bytes.

So I *think* you want the Unicode code points.  In that case:

```
def shift_jis2unicode(charcode): # charcode is an integer
    if charcode <= 0xFF:
        shift_jis_string = chr(charcode)
    else:
        shift_jis_string = chr(charcode >> 8) + chr(charcode & 0xFF)

    unicode_string = shift_jis_string.decode('shift-jis')

    assert len(unicode_string) == 1
    return ord(unicode_string)

print "U+%04X" % shift_jis2unicode(0x8144)
print "U+%04X" % shift_jis2unicode(0x51)
```

(Also: I don't think 8100 is a valid shift-JIS character code...)

Comment: 8100 was kind of a guess and a wrong one. Don't get the whole unicode vs utf-8 business. I think you are right though.

Comment: @AlexC, Unicode strings are made up of codepoints (generally one per character) and `ord` will convert a codepoint to an integer. UTF-8 is a representation of a codepoint in 1 or more 8-bit bytes.

Comment: For a good intro to Unicode and all the encoding issues, I recommend "The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)" - http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to do this, but since there are no other answers yet here is an option.

You could use [this table](http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/OBSOLETE/EASTASIA/JIS/SHIFTJIS.TXT) to convert your shift-jis integers to unicode code points, then use [`unichr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unichr) to convert your data into a Python unicode object, and then convert it from unicode to utf8 using [`unicode.encode('utf-8')`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings).

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using a custom table. I thought if I could use what Python provides, the code would be cleaner and I wouldn't need to have an extra file holding all the character codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def from_shift_jis(seq):
    chars = [chr(c) if c <= 0xff else chr(c>>8) + chr(c&0xff) for c in seq]
    return ''.join(chars).decode('shift-jis')

utf8_output = [ord(c) for c in from_shift_jis(shift_jis_input).encode('utf-8')]
```

Comment: What does "chr(c>>8) + chr(c&0xff)" do?

Comment: @AlexC, `c>>8` shifts the upper 8 bits of the integer into the lower 8 bits, and `c&0xff` strips off the upper 8 bits. It's a way of splitting an integer into two 8-bit parts. The `chr` converts to a character as you know, and `+` appends them into a two-character string.

Comment: OK. I'm having trouble now actually converting the unicode string to an utf-8 character code integer. I'll update my question with the code I have so far, please have a look.

Comment: @AlexC, I think you want `0x8100` rather than `8100` in your test code.

Comment: I think 0xFF and 255 are the exact same thing in Python. Still an error anyway.

Comment: @AlexC, yes 0xFF and 255 are the same but that's not what I was talking about. `0x8100` is a valid shift-jis character but `8100` is not.

Comment: It is? shift-jis codec fails to decode it. Anyway, the real problem is ord() accepts a char (string of lenght 1), while we pass a two byte string to it. Got to think of something else...

Comment: @AlexC, did you try running the exact code I gave you? It should work fine, returning a list of ints each of which is a utf-8 byte.

Comment: @AlexC, sorry you're correct - 0x8100 isn't valid shift-jis, it starts at 0x8140.